# servlet session not same when in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat6, sessionid

I am creating a session id

`HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);`

in login servlet and calling welcome page from there...printing session values in both the pages

`<% System.out.println(session.getID()); %>`. Though these session values comes same on my local machine and local tomcat server, when I run it on remote tomcat server I am getting two different session values. Is there any configuration setting in Tomcat which might affect this. I am using `java1.6, Tomcat6.0.25, xml2.4`.
Can anyone help me with this weird issue.

I recently noticed that set-cookie PATH is set to "/website-name" while I saw that several online documents say "Path=/". Can this be a problem and where/how to change this path to see its effects?

[SOLVED]

Comment: Is the remote tomcat clustered?

Comment: i dont have deep understanding of servers. what do we mean by clustered?

Comment: ask your system administrator then.

Comment: i have pushed this query to the administrator, but is there any good link which could explain me how clustered tomcat will matter for session tracking.

Comment: Confirmed it. Tomcat is not using clustered config at remotr server

Comment: You are getting what two different session values? You realize you are printing `HttpSession.toString()`, which may or may not consist solely of the session ID, which is the only thing that needs to be unique.

Comment: my bad, changed the code to print session ID. Still getting different values for session ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be something considered good programming trick, but this problem required changing the sessioncookiepath value at web-app>METAINF>context.xml file. For particularly my problem, putting following code helped: Context sessionCookiePath="" This might be due to my website structure.